# How to make pdf not downloadable on android devices?

Tags: android, pdf

I have offline web application and client have request for safety of company custom pdf documents. Web application is php on server side and js(handlebars) + offlineIndexedDb for offline regime.

I have not very experiens with pdf guarding, my initial idea is, if there is any way for php/js to turn pdf to base64 i could store it do IndexedDB(not sure with hardisk limits but should be possible to do 100-300mb i guess) , and if ther eixist solid enough js library for inbrowser pdf visualisation (with possibility to set no save/download in config), but that library would have to be able to process that base64 form at all.

If you could advice any js/php library that could be helpfull at this topic.

I have manual access to all android tablets that would need this protection.
So another idea is, that there could exist open-source/free client-server android application that could be used for viewing pdfs but with prohibited/guarded pdf download possibilities. But till now i did not found that kind of application, if you know any usefull app that could solve this problem, please advice me .

Comment: There's no bulletproof way to do this. What if the user were to take screenshots? Sure, you might find a way to disable that. But you can't prevent a user from taking a picture of the screen with another device. In the end there's no way to give the user the data and not _give the user the data._

Comment: Matt's right, so your goal is just to make it difficult.  The best you can do is store it in private data, but the part I don't know about is displaying the PDF file inside your app.  I think you'll find that is the hard part.  Solve that, and then either just store the PDF in the private area, or if you want to add an extra hoop, store it in the db as base64 like you said.  Decoding from base64 is no big deal.  BTW anyone with root access will be able to get at the PDF no matter what you do.